# multilingual site : including language file

Tags: php, multilingual

I got some work related to multilingual. before going to live I tried a demo at my local. I am using different language files for different languages.

These languages are having different variables in it. When I  include that language file in my main file then it shows **?** characters instead of spanish/purtogish text. My HTML page charset is UTF-8 which is ok.

When I don't inlclude the file and directly have the variables in my main file then it works ??

can any body help where is the problem ??

Sample Text 
: $lang['zip_code'] = "código postal";

Comment: Can you add a sample of what there is in your spanish translation file?

Comment: If you're getting `?` symbols for text in the browser, you probably have an encoding issue.  It could be that you're using some PHP function that is not multi-byte safe and it is returning a bad result.

Comment: Try calling `utf8_decode` on your translation before displaying it ($lang['zip_code']).

Comment: Well only change one to see if it's the problem, when I'm having encoding problems I usually try `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode` functions.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrier I tried to encode it in the file and then directly used the variable and it worked. Should I need to do this for each and every varialbe ????

Comment: Sounds a bit awful I agree ... maybe right after you require the translation file you can loop through the `$lang` array and apply the utf8_decode function on each key => param